# assigning values to a field of an structure array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to replace the value of the fields in a structure array. For example, I want to replace all 1's with 3's in the following construction.

```
a(1).b = 1;
a(2).b = 2;
a(3).b = 1;

a([a.b] == 1).b = 3; % This doesn't work and spits out:
% "Insufficient outputs from right hand side to satisfy comma separated
% list expansion on left hand side.  Missing [] are the most likely cause."
```

Is there an easy syntax for this? I want to avoid ugly for loops for such simple operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credits go to @Slayton, but you actually can do the same thing for assigning values too, using [deal](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/deal.html):

```
[a([a.b]==1).b]=deal(3)
```

So breakdown:

```
[a.b]
```

retrieves all `b` fields of the array `a` and puts this [comma-separated-list](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-4) in an array.

```
a([a.b]==1)
```

uses logical indexing to index only the elements of `a` that satisfy the constraint. Subsequently the full command above assigns the value `3` to all elements of the resulting comma-separated-list according to [this](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-8).

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve that the value of a field for each struct in an array using `cell` notation.

```
bVals = {a.b};
bVals = cell2mat( bVals );
```

AFAIK, you can't do the same thing for inserting values into an array of structs. You'll have to use a loop.

Comment: you actually can do the same thing for inserting values, using [deal](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/deal.html): `[a([a.b]==1).b]=deal(3)`

Comment: @GuntherStruyf your answer is great. But it wouldn't make sense to make the original response as answer though. Could you post it as a separate reply (for others)?