# Preallocate Structure for Movie in Matlab

Tags: matlab, movie

I would like to preallocate the following structure before a for-loop. It is used to save `M=getframe(i)`.

[image]

I tried the following:

```
M=struct(cdata, zeros(1,559), colormap);
```

Which logically comes up with:

```
Undefined function or variable 'cdata'.
```

**Question**
Is there a way to pre-allocate the structure for a movie directly ? Or do I have to assign 343x434x3 uint 8 to cdata ? (And if yes how would I do that?).

**EDIT**
I guess this is not a duplicate of the following thread, as this is specially about the pre-allocation of a movie struct. 
[How to initialize an array of structs in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664090/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-structs-in-matlab)

@ Luis Mendo

I tried pre-allocating your way:

comes up with the following problem:

```
Conversion to uint8 from struct is not possible.

Error in UG9 (line 238)
M(i)=getframe;
```

I would be glad for any help, maybe I just dont understand the method of pre-allocating as described in the above thread.

Comment: Since you have no colormap and all `cdata` are the same size, why not just use a 4D array? `M = zeros(343,343,8,559, 'uint8');` and then fill it with `M(:,:,:,counter) = ...`

Comment: If you were to read the documentation for struct you'd see that the first input needs to be a string, because it's the name of a field...

Comment: And it is the same, there is no such thing as a "movie struct" in MATLAB. A structure is a structure.

Comment: Where is the 1,559 coming from? I don't see that in your table.

Comment: thats dependant on the loop as a frame is saved everytime the loop creates a new "picture" for the movie